# Three.js: how to punch multiple holes in a shape without distortions?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to punch some simple square holes in a complex Three.js shape with :

```
var Shape1 = new THREE.Shape(ShapeCoordinates1);
PunchHole1 = new THREE.Path(Punchcoordinates1);
PunchHole2 = new THREE.Path(Punchcoordinates2);
Shape1.holes.push(PunchHole1);
Shape1.holes.push(PunchHole2);
```

etc.

Because of the irregular shape, with vertex coordinates that probably overlap with punched holes, this goes terribly wrong when punching out *multiple* holes, like this :
[image]

This should be a solid outlined shape with only around 30 small square holes punched out of it, so *not* the huge diagonal white spaces in the middle .

Is there a way in Three.js to prevent this behaviour ?

Comment: If the holes overlap, it will not likely work. Also read [this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3386), where you will find links to alternative libraries.