# Shape with single hole: "Probably Hole outside Shape!"

Tags: three.js

I try to create a simple rectangle with a hole using a Shape for the main geometry and Path for the hole as follows:

```
    var shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo(0, -100);
    shape.lineTo(0, 100);
    shape.lineTo(400, 100);
    shape.lineTo(400, -100);

    var hole = new THREE.Path();
    hole.moveTo(25, -75);
    hole.lineTo(25, 75);
    hole.lineTo(375, 75);
    hole.lineTo(375, -75);

    shape.holes.push(hole);
    geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
```

From this code I get a console error like this one:

> Infinite Loop! Holes left:1, Probably Hole outside Shape!

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I see from the hard-coded coordinates the hole has coordinates that are inside the big shape.

I had a look to some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702450/three-js-how-to-punch-multiple-holes-in-a-shape-without-distortions) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337364/simple-holes-arent-rendered-properly-in-three-js) and [examples](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html) already but I am unable to see the differences or what is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify your points in counterclockwise winding order.

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(0, -100);
shape.lineTo(400, -100);
shape.lineTo(400, 100);
shape.lineTo(0, 100);

var hole = new THREE.Path();
hole.moveTo(25, -75);
hole.lineTo(375, -75);
hole.lineTo(375, 75);
hole.lineTo(25, 75);
```

three.js r.68

Comment: Totally right! What worries me is that I did not find anything on the documentation regarding this... so, thanks a lot @WestLangley

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to close the path. So add

```
shape.lineTo(0, -100);
```

and to the hole

```
hole.lineTo(25, -75);
```

Comment: This option was one of my first try but didn't have any effect.